# Proper way to write efficient CRUD operation in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

Here is the controller that i have so far

```
router.get('/:scribbleId',function(req,res,next) {
  scribble.findOne({_id:req.params.scribbleId},function(err,object) {
    if(err)
      res.status(500).end();
    if(object == null)
      res.status(404).end();
    else {
      if(object.owner == req.user) {
        res.status(200).json(object);
      }else if(object.is_public == true) {
        res.status(200).json(object);
      }else {
        res.status(403).end();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

and there is a `middleware` just before that at `Router` level

```
var user   = require('../models/User.js');
var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('../settings');

module.exports = function (req,res,next) {
  var token = req.get("authorization");
  if (!token) {
    res.set("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Authorization Required\"");
    res.status(403).send("Authorization Required");
  }else {
    jwt.verify(token,config.secret,function(err,decoded) {
      if(err) {
        res.set("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Authorization Required\"");
        res.status(403).send("Authorization Required");
      }else {
        userId = decoded.id;
        req.user = userId;
        next();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

The problem that `mocha` tests take a lot of time in the operations. Below is some of the cases

```
Tests for GET verb
  ✓ Root endpoint returns 403 without token
  ✓ Root endpoint should return 200 with valid token (94ms)
  ✓ Return proper json object if owner (109ms)
  ✓ Return proper json object if public (88ms)
  ✓ Return 404 if scribble not found (91ms)
```

Being new to `nodejs` and the `red` stamp of colors i am assuming that the code i wrote is not the most efficient one. What i need help is in identifying what part am i going wrong and making that blocking. Also would appreciate if you can also link some tools that i can use to profile the express application.

> Just a note, i am just talking if the current controller is written properly. Not about the caching part which i know can increase the efficiency of my api.

Comment: FYI, your code has paths that can call `res.end()` more than once.  You don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is pretty efficient. I bet because your Mocha tests are running against a real HTTP server, the red timestamp are where setting up and tearing down TCP connection costs.

To speed things up, you can expose your controller code and use Mocha to test against it directly. And you may also want to apply the same pattern to your middleware code.